# Deploying web services on a RHEL 5 box using Apache/Tomcat/Axis/Java

Tags: linux, java, tomcat, service, axis

I am new to the Web services scene. I currently have access to a RHEL5 box and i need to deploy a java web service on it. It runs apache and i know this because i have a website hosted on this machine.

Now, i want to deploy a web service on to this website to be able to just pass a link to someone when they need to access my web service.

Could someone point out a resource or explain what all i need to get the webservice deployed using Tomcat/Apache Axis and Java. I have done this on Windows (hosted on localhost) but couldn't quite figure out things on linux.

Any help is greatly appreciated. 
Thanks.
Deepak.

Answer (score 1):

1. l00k at that: http://linuxgazette.net/issue95/millson.html
2. deploy axis2.war to your tomcat
3. install your .aar file to the axis2 servlet
4. buy me a beer ;-)

Comment: #4 is by far the best response ever..